# Refresh split view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, reload

I have a universal application with a list of items (loaded from a backend) and item details (loaded from a backend as well). Each view controller listens to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, so that the view is refreshed when the user (re-)opens the app. That works so far.

Now my problem. On iPad, I have a split view. So, when the user (re-)opens the app in landscape, both views are reloaded. If there is no connection to the backend, the user gets two alerts with Retry/Cancel options, one above the other. That is not what I want... I have one default item which does not require connection to the backend and I want to set it to be selected and to display its details in the detail view. Always when the originally selected item is missing in the master view.

What I have done so far... In my master view controller, I check whether the selected item is available after the refresh and if not, I update the selection and the detail view. This should solve the problem when the requests from the left and from the right pane are processed in the correct order. However, currently both view controllers get the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and make asynchronous requests to the backend.

Has someone experience in refreshing split views? What would be the right way to solve my problem? I really don't want to introduce additional notifications/complexity. I hope, there is some standard way to reload the data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution.

I create for each view controller a property `alertView` and store there the alert view that is displayed. In `viewWillDisappear`, I dismiss this alert view. So, when the details for my default item are displayed to the right, the alert view of the "old" controller is dismissed and I have only one alert view.

It is for sure not the perfect solution and I would be happy if someone can give me a better one. But for now, that works fine.